# What's wrong with the following limit evaluation?

Tags: calculus, limits, fake-proofs

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to \infty} \ln{x}&=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\ln{x}}{x}\cdot x\\
&=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\ln{x}}{x}\cdot \lim_{x \to \infty} x\\
&=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{(\ln{x})'}{x'}\cdot \lim_{x \to \infty} x\text{ [Using l'hopital]}\\
&=\lim_{x \to \infty} 1/x \cdot \lim_{x \to \infty} x=\lim_{x \to \infty} 1/x\cdot x=1
\end{align*}

Comment: $\lim f(x)\lim g(x)=\lim f(x)g(x)$ is only true if $\lim f(x)$ and $\lim g(x)$ exist. Here, you've twice applied this with $g(x)=x,$ where $\lim g(x)$ does not exist.

Comment: $\infty=\lim_{x \to \infty}\ln x=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\ln{x}}{x}\cdot x\ne\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\ln{x}}{x}\cdot \lim_{x \to \infty} x$ because the r.h.s. is indeterminate ($0\cdot\infty$). Similarly, $\lim_{x \to \infty} 1/x \cdot \lim_{x \to \infty} x\ne\lim_{x \to \infty} 1/x\cdot x=1$ because the l.h.s.  is indeterminate ($0\cdot\infty$).